# Is it possible to condense a set of HTML documentation, including all links, into a single PDF, EBook etc?

Tags: html, pdf

I essentially want to produce and EBook, or PDF file from a large set of HTML documentation. Is there any code/app that could help? Is it theoretically, or realistically, possible???

Or do I need to RTFM :)

Answer (score 1):

As for PDFs,

I work on a project where users author large (400+ pages) documents. We output documents in HTML and send them to [DocRaptor](https://docraptor.com/).  DocRaptor uses [PrinceXML](https://www.princexml.com/) under the hood. For the project we went with DocRaptor due to costs.  We don't output very much and have a tiny budget.  The output from PrinceXML is great.